# Rust official tutorial multithreaded web server with mockito tests - empty request

Tags: multithreading, tcp, rust, mockito, steam

I am trying to write integration tests for the official multithreaded web server tutorial.

In `integrational_tests.rs`, I have something like this:

```
fn connect_and_send_request() {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:7879").unwrap();
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(stream);
    let s = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    writer.write(s).unwrap();
    writer.flush().unwrap();
}

fn test_main_route() {
    let server_address = [SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 7879))];

    let listener: TcpListener = TcpListener::bind(&server_address[..]).unwrap();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);

    connect_and_send_request();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();

        pool.execute(|| {
            let main_mock = mock("GET", "/").create();
            handle_connection(stream);
            println!("Main mock {}", main_mock);
            main_mock.assert();
        });
    }

    fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
        let mut response = [0; 512];
        stream.read(&mut response).unwrap();
        stream.flush().unwrap();
        println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&response[..]));
    }
}
```

In my "Request" `println!` I see my request string, but `main_mock.assert()` based on Mockito fails:

```
thread <unnamed> panicked at assertion failed: (left == right) 
expect GET / ... but recived 0.
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? It looks like you're creating a TCP server on `127.0.0.1:7879` and then sending a request to that same port. And then accepting that connection and printing the first written packet - which works as expected. But then you're mocking a server on port 1234 too and never sending anything to it but expecting it to have been called?

Comment: If you're trying to write tests for the multithreaded server, why do you need to mock anything? Can't you just send it requests from your test?

Comment: He's not creating a server on `127.0.0.1:7879`, he's mocking a server on this address and checking that the client called the server. And where do you see port 1234 in the question?

Comment: I don't know enough about Mockito to be sure, but could the issue come from the fact that you send the request (through `connect_and_send_request`) before you create the mock, so by the time the mock is created the request is already passed and the mock doesn't see it?

Comment: Mockito creates a HTTP server on port 1234. It has no idea about his TCP listener

Comment: https://docs.rs/mockito/0.12.0/mockito/constant.SERVER_ADDRESS.html

Comment: Thanks Matt - i try diff approach to make this work correctly without Mockito mock.

Comment: I think this problem would be much easier to solve with a more modern HTTP mocking library, such as https://crates.io/crates/httpmock (shameless plug).